# reactJS fetch json data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

I am  new to JS and reactJS.
I want to get info from API to an array. I made API that show all the info from my database.
It looks like this:

[image: press here]

```
const [tempNew, setTempNew] = useState([]);
const getAllWeatherCelsius = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/weather')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((jsonData) => {
        let tmpArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
          tmpArray.push(jsonData.dayCelsius[i])   <---- here is the error
        }
        setTempNew(tmpArray);
      })
  }
```

I want to collect all values from **"dayCelsius"** line into array.

What do I need to change in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide more info about the error? But You can try using the map function like

```
 const tmpArray = jsonData.map(r => r.dayCelsius);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` function to return the `dayCelsius` value of each element and store them in the `tmpArray`.

```
let tmpArray = jsonData.map((el, i) => el.dayCelsius);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what I understand is that you are facing difficulty in just getting the `dayCelsius` value from the array of objects you fetch from your API.

It is difficult to make out what the problem is as more info  about the error is required to see what is going wrong.

What I have done differently here is instead of the for-loop and `jsonData.dayCelsius[i]`, I have used `data.map((r,e) => r.dayCelsius)`.

> ```
> const [temp, setTemp] = useState([]);
> const getAllWeatherCelsius = () => {
>     fetch('http://localhost:5000/weather', {
>         method: "GET",
>         headers: {
>             Accept: "application/json",
>             "Content-Type": "application/json",
>         }
>     })
>       .then(response => {
>         return response.json();
>       })
>       .then((data) => {
>         const tempArray = data.map((r,e) => r.dayCelsius); 
>         setTemp(tempArray);
>       })
>       .catch(err => console.log(err));
>   }
> ```

I hope it helps you, have a good day :)